# How to create a secure, production ready private chain?

Tags: private-blockchain

I'm looking for more information or resources on how to run a private chain with ethereum with multiple nodes that would work in production and would only be accessible to my users/network.

I know all about the dev private network but as stated it's "for testing purposes only".

The question is somewhat vague but important as i have no clue what would be needed and would require many different questions ( how many nodes?miners?hardware?software? security ? ).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is a private chain? Is this similar to a testnet or is it just a simulation, if so, what do you gain from testing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a private "consortium" based Ethereum blockchain in about 12 mins on Microsoft's Cloud the last time i did it. I did a video on it a while back jump to the end of the video to see the deployment of the script.

https://youtu.be/HsConsFaZG8

I would start with the deployment walk through document below,

Here is Microsoft's updated walk through of building, configuring and deploying Ethereum private consortium blockchain complete with mining nodes and transaction nodes. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Ethereum-Consortium-b0e1bc65

then to get up and running in an automated way use the quickstart template

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-blockchain-ethereum?tab=Overview

Comment: Link to your video isn't working but i'm interesting. Do you have an other one? EDIT: or a link to your channel.

Comment: updated link https://youtu.be/HsConsFaZG8

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your chain in such a way if you want to make ready for implementing in enterprise level firstly you may use as a test network. check whether it is perfect for production level or not. Ok cool, What we do generally to make the ethereum chain is :-

```
Define all parameter for genesis block, Genesis block is the first block for the chain. 
 Gas Limit : Gas limit is cumulative gas defined by the transactions  
 Block Time : time to start new block after competition of current block
 Network ID : ID that represent your Blockchain 
 Network name : Name that represent your Blockchain
 And One important thing is what consensus engine you want to use (POA,POW,POS)
```

**I will present here How I did for Titan Blockchain

Setting up node A.**

```
 /home/gopal/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --titan  --nodiscover console
```

Then we get enode address as below:
Enode :  `"enode://e089f89a518c739b7e63198cc62c7619544dd2daf0d531188ad9a46130d12a84fa78b2b4172a3c59ebe0fc1738cc47725655f553eaa70dfbbe8cb2a5fdcacd4e@[::]:30303?discport=0"`

**Setting up node B**

```
 /home/gopal/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --titan  --datadir "t2" --port 30305 --nodiscover console
```

Again we get enode address of node B as:

Enode : `"enode://c370f6396a3aa439494405a241565128d513b921d2944cebfb10fb13c6db46bbd4e4dad02b585b0a14e9f6d2d756233763825d287328523429eb592ade1a7d42@[::]:30305?discport=0"`

Now lets peer two node each other as:

> admin.addPeer(“_enode_of_node_A”)

Now check if peering or not :

> admin.peers

If you want host the node in cloud then [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-to-host-a-blockchain-application/52481?noredirect=1#comment62247_52481) is detail how to work on it. 
and also useful to you is [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52529/how-to-add-peers-to-a-private-blockchain-network-without-using-ip-address)