# How to host a blockchain application?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, truffle, tokens, private-blockchain

I have started working in blockchain for the last few weeks. I have created a private blockchain in my system using geth and added peers by using admin.addPeer() command. I have also created an application that uses this blockchain. In my application, I have used web3 to connect to the blockchain from front-end and I have also written some smart contracts which controls the activities of that application. After all this, I have also written a smart contract(ERC Tokens) to create cryptocurrencies which is used for payments in that application. It works well when I hosted in my private network. But now I want to host it to another server so that we can use that application from anywhere. Is truffle an option?

Can anyone help me to do this? And I would also like to know the system requirements or architecture of the server where the blockchain applications has to be hosted and also how to connect peers to a network by using the public IP address instead of local IP address. As local IP can change according the network it has connected.

Answer (score 3):

You mean that you want to host **Ethereum node** on server so that you can enable  RPC and use the node. This is also cool idea. I have done this in AWS(amazon web services). This is most easiest way to interact with node globally without any concern.
I will share all the things that you have to do in aws. I did this for [Titan](http://www.blockchain.rosebayconsult.com/) private network  - forked from go-ethereum. It is same for other and also for official go-ethereum .

```
Prerequisite:
Account in AWS
Basic understanding of Titan
Externally owned account (EOA)
Ethereum keystore file

Create ec2 instance:  
1. Launc ec2 instance   
2. Choose an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) ( Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM )   
3. Choose an Instance Type ( t2.medium )   
4. Configure Security Group   
And launch.

Select and existing key pair or create a new key pair and Launch Instance. Save key pair in local computer. 

5. Connect to ec2 instance by ssh  e.g. ssh -i "titanaws.pem" ubuntu@ec2-18-188-87-71.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
(titanaws.pem is key to access to ubuntu instance in AWS.)
```

> Setup Titan node:     Building the source    Building Geth (command line
>   client)    Install latest distribution of Go    git clone
>   https://github.com/gopal/golang-tools-install-script   cd
>   golang-tools-install-script   bash goinstall.sh --64    or   wget
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
>   sudo tar -xvf go1.7.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz    sudo mv go /usr/local
>   export GOROOT=/usr/local/go   export
>   PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH

```
Clone the repository to a directory of your choosing:   
git clone https://github.com/RoseBay-Consulting/Titan.git  
Building geth requires Go and C compilers to be installed:   
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential golang   
sudo apt install make    
sudo apt install gcc   
cd Titan   
make geth   
Running Geth:  
Full node on the Titan network   
cd ~ Titan/build/bin/geth --titan console     

 We copy and paste the keystore file in ~/.titan/titan/keystore. An keystore file (stored in ~/.titan/titan/keystore) is an encrypted version of your unique private key that you will use to sign your transactions.  
The file should look something like this:  
UTC--2015-09-18T14-07-57.023663538Z--da78c8721e4ede42cf488304551eb596dd5f93e23
```

> If you want to use your own machine and access node then you have to
>   configure static IP . May ISP will provide a specific port.

This may help you!!

Comment: Thank you Gopal for a detailed answer..... I gonna try this for sure.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Truffle is just a framework for developing ethereum based decentralized application. You can host your application on IPFS. [This link](https://blog.de-swaef.eu/using-ipfs-to-host-your-dapp/) is useful for how you can host your decentralized application on IPFS.
[This link](https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/the-ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-and-deploy-a-fully-descentralized-dapp-in-ethereum-18f0cf6d7e0e) is useful for how to develop an application using truffle and how to deploy it on IPFS.