# How to add peers to a private blockchain network without using IP address?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, peers

I have created a private blockchain network and added peers to that network using the `admin.addPeers()` command. But the problem is, in that method I have to give the local IP address of the system which can be changed at any moment and results in **peer disconnection**.
Can anyone suggest some other method that can be used so the I can have a stable connection between the peers of the network?

Comment: you need ip address in any cost , whether you connect locally or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you need one static ip so that you connect with the node having same ip all the time.
You can do this by [port forwarding](https://www.pcworld.com/article/244314/how_to_forward_ports_on_your_router.html) or own [static ip](https://support.google.com/fiber/answer/3547208?hl=en).

Enode is in the form of

> "enode://e089f89a518c739b7e63198cc62c7619544dd2daf0d531188ad9a46130d12a84fa78b2b4172a3c59ebe0fc1738cc47725655f553eaa70dfbbe8cb2a5fdcacd4e@[::]:30303?discport=0"

`[::]` is for the ip. if you are connecting locally then it doesnot matter because your router will maintain this. 
In case of public, there should be public ip. ok now how it looks like :

> "enode://e089f89a518c739b7e63198cc62c7619544dd2daf0d531188ad9a46130d12a84fa78b2b4172a3c59ebe0fc1738cc47725655f553eaa70dfbbe8cb2a5fdcacd4e@172.31.40.193:30303"

This may help you.